# Relam iOS database

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

If I use Realm in my SDK, when someone embed's my SDK in their app and they are also using Realm would there be any conflict? or am I better off just sticking to CoreData.

I'm looking at moving to Realm because I like the thread safety aspect of it and the number of queries it can perform per second.

Comment: Welcome to SO. While this is a good question, it's probably not a good question for this site. The questions here are coding related questions and this is more of a legalities and copy write question. You should reach out to Realm support directly.  *Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tool*

Answer (score 0):

If you ensure that you use a custom Realm database - not the default - then you should be okay to use Realm in your SDK.  Projects can contain multiple Realm databases without a problem.